if $Z\rightarrow X$ is closed immersion then $f:Y\rightarrow X$ factors through X iff $f^{\ast}\mathscr I\rightarrow f^{\ast}\mathscr O_X$ is zero
The following is Lemma 01HP at the Stacks Project:

Lemma. Let $X,Y$ be locally ringed space. Let $\mathscr I\subset \mathscr O_X$ be sheaf of ideals locally generated by sections. Let $i:Z\rightarrow X$ be associated closed space. A morphism $f:Y\rightarrow X$ factors through $Z$ if and only if the map $f^* \mathscr I\rightarrow f^*\mathscr O_X=\mathscr O_Y$ is zero. If this is the case then the morphism is unique.
Proof. Clearly if $f$ factors as $Y\rightarrow Z\rightarrow X$ then the map $f^* \mathscr I\rightarrow \mathscr O_Y$ is zero. Conversely, suppose that $f^* \mathscr I\rightarrow \mathscr O_Y$ is zero. Pick any $y\in Y$, and consider the ring map $f_y^{\sharp}:\mathscr O_{X,f(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{Y,y}$. Since the composition $\mathscr I_{f(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{X,f(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{Y,y}$ is zero by assumption and since $f_y(1)=1$ we see that $1\not\in \mathscr I_{f(y)}$,i.e., $\mathscr I_{f(y)}\neq \mathscr O_{X,f(y)}$. we conclude that $f(Y)\subset Z=\operatorname{Supp}(\mathscr O_X/\mathscr I)$. Hence $f=i\circ g$ where $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is continuous. Consider the map $f^{\sharp}:\mathscr O_X\rightarrow f_* \mathscr O_Y$. The assumption $f^* \mathscr I\rightarrow f^* \mathscr O_X$ is zero implies that the composition $\mathscr I\rightarrow \mathscr O_X\rightarrow f^* \mathscr O_Y$ is zero by adjointness of $f^{\ast}$ and $f_{\ast}$. In other words, we obtain a morphism of sheaves of rings $\bar{f^{\sharp}}$ :$\mathscr O_X/\mathscr I\rightarrow f_{\ast} \mathscr O_Y$. Note that $f_{\ast}\mathscr O_Y=i_{\ast}g_{\ast}\mathscr O_Y$ and that $\mathscr O_X/\mathscr I=i_{\ast}\mathscr O_Z$. We obtain a unique morphism of sheaves of rings $g^{\sharp}:\mathscr O_Z\rightarrow g_{\ast} \mathscr O_Y$ whose pushforward under $i$ is $\bar{f^{\sharp}}$. We omit the verification that $(g,g^{\sharp})$ defines a morphsim of locally ringed spaces and that $f=i\circ g$ as a morphism of locally ringed spaces.

Here are the parts which I do not understand.

if $f$ factors as $Y\rightarrow Z\rightarrow X$ then the map $f^* \mathscr I\rightarrow \mathscr O_Y$ is zero.

Why is this true? I think if $f=i\circ g$, then $f^{\ast}\mathscr I=(i\circ g)^{\ast}\mathscr I=g^{\ast}(i^{\ast}\mathscr I)=g^{\ast}(0)=0$. Here $i^{\ast} \mathscr I=\mathscr O_Z\otimes_{i^{-1}\mathscr O_X}i^{-1}\mathscr I=i^{-1}(\mathscr O_X/\mathscr I)\otimes_{i^{-1}\mathscr O_X}i^{-1}\mathscr I=0$. Is that correct?

Since the composition $\mathscr I_{f(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{X,f(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{Y,y}$ is zero by assumption

Why is this composition is zero by assumption? What I think is by using adjointness of $f^{\ast}$ and $f_{\ast}$, we can obtain $f_{\ast}f^{\ast}\mathscr I=\mathscr I\rightarrow f_{\ast}f^{\ast}\mathscr O_X=\mathscr O_X\rightarrow f_{\ast}\mathscr O_Y$, once we apply $f_{\ast}$ functor to the assumption $f^{\ast}\mathscr I\rightarrow f^{\ast} \mathscr O_X=\mathscr O_Y$.

Construction of $g^{\sharp}:\mathscr O_Z\rightarrow g_{\ast}\mathscr O_Y$.

I think we need to use adjunction of $i_{\ast}$ and $i^{\ast}$. In the proof we already obtain a morphism $\mathscr O_X/\mathscr I=i_{\ast}\mathscr O_Z\rightarrow f_{\ast}\mathscr O_Y=i_{\ast}g_{\ast}\mathscr O_Y$, then we apply $i^{\ast}$ functor to this morphism.

Verification that $g$ indeed defines a map of locally ringed spaces.

What I think is we need to verify that $\mathscr O_{Z,g(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{Y,y}$ is a local ring homomorphism, i.e. $(g^{\sharp})^{-1}(m_y)=m_{g(y)}$. But$(i^{\sharp})^{-1}(g^{\sharp})^{-1}(m_y)=(f^{\sharp})^{-1}(m_y)=m_{f(y)}\Rightarrow (i^{\sharp})^{-1}((g^{\sharp})^{-1}(m_y))=m_{f(y)}$, because $i^{\sharp}$ is a local ring homomorphism then we conclude that $(g^{\sharp})^{-1}(m_y)=m_{g(y)}$. Not sure if I am correct.
Just below the proof there is also a easy consequence which I do not know how to proof.
Lemma 01HQ at the Stacks Project:

Lemma. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of locally ringed spaces. Let $\mathscr I\subset \mathscr O_Y$ be a sheaf of ideals which is locally generated by sections. Let $i:Z\rightarrow Y$ be the closed subspace associated to the sheaf of ideals $\mathscr I$. Let $\mathscr J$ be the image of the map $f^{\ast}\mathscr I\rightarrow f^{\ast} \mathscr O_Y=\mathscr O_X$. Then this ideal is locally generated by sections. Moreover, let $i':Z'\rightarrow X$ be the associated closed subspace of $X$. There exists a unique morphism of locally ringed spaces $f':Z'\rightarrow Z$ such that the following diagram commuets. Moreover, this diagram is a fibre product in the category of locally ringed spaces.
Proof. The ideal $\mathscr J$ is locally generated by sections. The rest follows from the lemma above.

For the first half of this lemma I think we mainly need to show $(f\circ i')^{\ast} \mathscr I\rightarrow (f\circ i')^{\ast}\mathscr O_Y$ is zero, but I do not know how to show.
In the very end we also have to show this is a fibre product square and I also do not know how to show. Note that this lemma in particular says if $i$ is closed immersion then its lift through fibre product diagram $i'$ is also a closed immersion.

I am sorry at the bottom I wanted to add the commutative square but when I copied the code it did not compile well.

Generally, $i^*\mathscr I\neq 0$. For example if you have an affine schemes and an ideal $I\subset A$, then $I\otimes_A (A/I) =I/I^2$, which is seldom zero. However the induced map $I/I^2 \to A/I$ is zero!


if $f$ factors as $Y\rightarrow Z\rightarrow X$ then the map $f^* \mathscr I\rightarrow \mathscr O_Y$ is zero.

Your logic is not correct. The pullback of $\mathcal{I}$ is not zero. For instance, consider when $\mathcal{I}$ is (locally) free, like $\mathcal{I}=\widetilde{(x)}$ as an ideal sheaf on $\Bbb A^1_k$.
I think Johan is writing the lemma with more attention paid to $f^*$, but I find it easier to work with $f_*$ here, so I'll focus on that a bit more. Write $i:Z\to X$ and $g:Y\to Z$ so that $f=i\circ g$. Then $\mathcal{O}_X\to f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ can be written as $\mathcal{O}_X\to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z \to i_*g_*\mathcal{O}_Y = f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$. As $\mathcal{I}$ is the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_X\to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$, we have that the composite morphism $\mathcal{I}\to \mathcal{O}_X \to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z \to f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is zero, or $\mathcal{I}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is zero. Now apply the adjunction $f^*\dashv f_*$ to get that $f^*\mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{O}_Y$ is zero.

Since the composition $\mathscr I_{f(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{X,f(y)}\rightarrow \mathscr O_{Y,y}$ is zero by assumption

Same logic as above: we get a sequence of maps $\mathcal{O}_{X,f(y)}\to \mathcal{O}_{Z,g(y)}\to\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$, and $\mathcal{I}_{f(y)}$ is the kernel of the first map.

Construction of $g^{\sharp}:\mathscr O_Z\rightarrow g_{\ast}\mathscr O_Y$.

If you know that $f^*\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{O}_Y$ is zero (but didn't follow the above, and so you don't know that $\mathcal{I}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is zero), the adjunction will give that $\mathcal{I}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is zero. Therefore by the universal property of the cokernel, we get a unique induced morphism $\operatorname{coker}(\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{O}_X) \cong i_*\mathcal{O}_Z \to f_*\mathcal{O}_Y \cong i_*g_*\mathcal{O}_Y$. But since $i$ is a closed immersion, this exactly specifies the map $\mathcal{O}_Z \to g_*\mathcal{O}_Y$.

Verification that $g$ indeed defines a map of locally ringed spaces.

You're right that all we need to do is to verify $\mathcal{O}_{Z,g(y)}\to \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is local. The sequence of maps $\mathcal{O}_{X,f(y)}\to \mathcal{O}_{Z,g(y)}\to\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ lets us conclude: the composite map is the local homomorphism defined by $f^\sharp$, and the first map is surjective and local.
For the final lemma, write $\varphi:Z'\to Y$ so that $f\circ i' = \varphi$. Then the previous lemma shows that $\varphi$ factors through $i:Z\to Y$ iff $\varphi^*\mathcal{I}\to\varphi^*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is the zero map. But that map is the pullback of $f^*\mathcal{I}\to f^*\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X$ by $(i')^*$, and $Z'$ is defined to be the sub-locally-ringed-space cut out by the image of that map, so the same logic as the first paragraph shows that the pullback of this map by $(i')^*$ is zero by writing $f^*\mathcal{I}\to f^*\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X$ as $f^*\mathcal{I}\to \mathcal{J}\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$.
To show the diagram is a fiber product square, it's quick to check that it satisfies the universal property. Suppose $T$ is a test scheme with maps $a:T\to Z$ and $b:T\to X$ so that the composites $T\to Z\to Y$ and $T\to X\to Y$ are equal. Then $c:T\to Y$ factors through $Z$, so $c^*\mathcal{I}\to c^*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is zero. But $c^*\mathcal{I}\to c^*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is the same as $b^*f^*\mathcal{I}\to b^*f^*\mathcal{O}_Y$, which has the same image as $b^*\mathcal{J}\to b^*\mathcal{O}_X$, so we just apply the above lemma to see that $b:T\to X$ factors uniquely through $Z'$ and we've shown the universal property of the fiber product.

Thank you a lot. One tiny question, in the construction of $g^{\sharp}$, you wrote 'But since $i$ is a closed immersion, this exactly specifies the map $\mathcal O_Z\rightarrow g_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y$'. Why is that? Is it anything nice about closed immersion that we want to use here? I originally thought just using the adjunction of $i_{\ast}$ and $i^{\ast}$.

@user11695417 it's the adjunction plus the fact that for a closed immersion $i:Z\to X$, the counit $i^i_\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism for all sheaves (you wouldn't be able to use this for an arbitrary map, for instance). A slightly lower-tech (or maybe just less dressed-up) level of seeing this is to note that $Z\subset X$ carries the subspace topology, so for any open $V\subset Z$ there exists an open $U\subset X$ so that $V=U\cap Z$ and therefore you can recover $\mathcal{F}(V)\to\mathcal{G}(V)$ as $(i_\mathcal{F})(U)\to (i_\mathcal{G})(U)$.
